# Consequences of positive integers $n, m_1, and m_2$ obeying $-m_2 < nx < m_1$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose we have positive integers $n, m_1, m_2$ obeying $$-m_2 < nx < m_1$$

According to my textbook (Baby Rudin), this means there exists an $m \in \mathbb Z$ with $-m_2 \leq m \leq m_1$ such that $$m-1 \leq nx < m$$

How is this acquired? More specifically, **(a)** how do we derive this consequence, and **(b)** why the change from $<$ to $\leq$ on only one side of the equation?

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Isn't $m-1$ just the integer part or floor function of $nx$? The change of $<$ to $\leq{}$ is in case $nx\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης It seems so obvious now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method that comes to my mind is to use to the floor of $nx$.

Let $\beta=\lfloor nx \rfloor=\sup \{z \in \mathbb{Z} | z \leq nx \}$. Since $m_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $nx<m_1$, the set $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} | nx \leq z \}$ is bounded above by $m_1$. Consequently we know that $\beta$ exists by the least upper bound property of $\mathbb{Z}$. We have,
$$\beta \leq nx.$$
Now we need to show that $nx<\beta+1$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $nx \geq \beta+1$. Then $\beta+1 \in \{z \in \mathbb{Z} | nx \leq z \}$, but this contradicts $\beta$ bounding $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} | nx \leq z \}$ from above since $\beta<\beta+1$. Therefore it must be that $nx < \beta+1$. So we have,
$$\beta \leq nx < \beta+1.$$
If you're so inclined you can substitute $m=\beta+1$, so that,
$$m-1 \leq nx \leq m$$